# Drupal - print the current/active sub theme

Tags: drupal

Im trying to get the path to the current theme (which is a sub theme) but I am having issues.

I have seen these 2 sites:

```
http://venutip.com/content/getting-path-your-subtheme
http://www.website-assistant.co.uk/web-developer/path-subtheme-drupal
```

Which has led me to this: (as an example)

**template.php**

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
 global $theme_key;
 $path_to_theme = drupal_get_path('theme', $theme_key);
}

?>
```

**page.tpl**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/<?php print $path_to_theme; ?>/css/print.css" media="print" type="text/css" />
```

But it doesnt work. What am I missing? I am using Drupal 6.19.

A.

Answer (score 1):

In your phptemplate_preprocess_node function, you need to add the $path_to_theme variable to the $vars array:

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  global $theme_key;
  $vars['path_to_theme'] = drupal_get_path('theme', $theme_key);
}
```

You are also able to add print CSS via the theme's .info file by adding a line like this:

stylesheets[print][] = css/print.css

The advantage of this approach is that your CSS files will be aggregated properly when CSS aggregation is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesnt seem to work still I'm afraid.

Comment: Have you rebuilt theme cache after defining the function? Also, see my edit about doing this via the theme's .info file